# How to set offset to SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation?

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, offset

How to set the `offset` point for `SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation`? Using following code the animation works well except I cannot set the offset point to middle of the `FrameworkElement`. Now the `offset` is at the left-upper corner.

```
       private static void ScaleAnimation_Internal(FrameworkElement TargetFrameworkElement, int ScaleInProsents, TimeSpan Duration, TimeSpan Delay, int DampingRatioProsent)
        {
            AnimationClass TargetAnimationClass = AddScaleAnimation(TargetFrameworkElement);
            Compositor TargetCompositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
            //UPDATE
            TargetAnimationClass.TargetSpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation.FinalValue = new Vector3((float)ScaleInProsents / 100);
            if (Duration != TimeSpan.Zero) TargetAnimationClass.TargetSpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation.Period = Duration;
            if (Delay != TimeSpan.Zero) TargetAnimationClass.TargetSpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation.DelayTime = Delay;
            if (DampingRatioProsent >= 0) TargetAnimationClass.TargetSpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation.DampingRatio = (float)DampingRatioProsent / 100;
            //START ANIMATION
            TargetFrameworkElement.StartAnimation(TargetAnimationClass.TargetSpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation);
        }
```

Comment: I checked `SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation` class, there is no such api setting offset point. This is api is too new to be known. For same approach, you could use Community tool kit Scale [animation](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/communitytoolkit/animations/scale).

Comment: Set the CenterPoint on the Visual associated with the TargetFrameworkElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Johnny Westlake said, you just need set the `CenterPoint` before `StartAnimation` invoked. For example

```
Compositor _compositor = Window.Current.Compositor;
SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation _springAnimation;

private void Btn_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.5f);
    (sender as UIElement).CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(Btn.ActualWidth / 2.0), (float)(Btn.ActualHeight / 2.0), 1f);
    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(_springAnimation);

}

private void Btn_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.0f);
    (sender as UIElement).CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(Btn.ActualWidth / 2.0), (float)(Btn.ActualHeight / 2.0), 1f);
    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(_springAnimation);


}
private void CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(float finalValue)
{
    if (_springAnimation == null)
    {
        _springAnimation = _compositor.CreateSpringVector3Animation();
        _springAnimation.Target = "Scale";

    }

    _springAnimation.FinalValue = new Vector3(finalValue);
}
```

**Xaml Code**

```
<Grid>
    <Button Name="Btn" Content="ClickMe" 
            PointerEntered="Btn_PointerEntered"
            PointerExited="Btn_PointerExited"
           VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >

    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanx, Nico Zhu! Your code example is simple and clear and it works as it should! I tried to solve this problem just too difficult way like it would be like a rocket science. I just didn't realise to use CentrePoint...

Answer (score 0):

Same as @Nico Zhu but rather than getting actual height from element directly, getting it from sender object.

```
Compositor _compositor = App.MainWindow.Compositor;
SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation _springAnimation;

private void CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(float finalValue)
{
    if (_springAnimation == null)
    {
        _springAnimation = _compositor.CreateSpringVector3Animation();
        _springAnimation.Target = "Scale";
    }

    _springAnimation.FinalValue = new Vector3(finalValue);
}

private void element_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Scale up to 1.5
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.5f);
    var element = sender as FrameworkElement; // Cast sender to FrameworkElement
    element.CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(element.ActualWidth / 2.0), (float)(element.ActualHeight / 2.0), 1f);
    element.StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
}

private void element_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Scale back down to 1.0
    CreateOrUpdateSpringAnimation(1.0f);
    var element = sender as FrameworkElement; // Cast sender to FrameworkElement
    element.CenterPoint = new Vector3((float)(element.ActualWidth / 2.0), (float)(element.ActualHeight / 2.0), 1f);
    element.StartAnimation(_springAnimation);
}
```