# Apply SpringAnimation in WinUI 3 starting from center point of polygon

Tags: c#, animation, polygon, scaling, winui-3

In a **WinUI 3** project I've applied a `SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation` to a `Polygon` shape object. The effect I'd like to obtain is a *scaling up/down animation* whenever the pointer enter/exit the polygon (it's a triangle) surface.

##### XAML

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas Name="Container" 
            Height="20" 
            Width="20" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Polygon x:Name="Cursor"
                 Points="0,20 10,0 20,20"
                 Fill="Green" />
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

##### Code

```cs
private readonly Compositor Compositor = CompositionTarget.GetCompositorForCurrentThread();
private SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation SpringAnimation;

private void Cursor_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CursorScaleAnimation(1.1f);
    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(SpringAnimation);
}

private void Cursor_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CursorScaleAnimation(1f);
    (sender as UIElement).StartAnimation(SpringAnimation);
}

private void CursorScaleAnimation(float value)
{
    if (SpringAnimation == null)
    {
        SpringAnimation = Compositor.CreateSpringVector3Animation();
        SpringAnimation.Target = "Scale";
    }

    SpringAnimation.FinalValue = new Vector3(value);
    SpringAnimation.DampingRatio = 0.6f;
    SpringAnimation.Period = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 60);
}
```

The above code works, but the issue is that the polygon is set to be centered on the container and the animation instead applies the scale from the `(0, 0)` point of the shape to the right. So, even if the scaling is small, you see the polygon moving a bit from the left to the right and vice-versa.
I'd like to apply the animation from the **center point of the polygon**. Is it possible? Maybe using a different kind of animation?

*P.S.: An additional question. I've also noticed (using a bigger scale factor) that the animation applies the scale to the polygon in a "non-vectorial way", like scaling an image over it's maximum resolution and so it loses a bit of it's definition. Since the polygon is a vectorial object, is there any way to scale it just by changing it's actual size (always from the center point)?*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set offset to SpringVector3NaturalMotionAnimation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54062967/how-to-set-offset-to-springvector3naturalmotionanimation)

Comment: @AndrewKeepCoding It seems to be the solution, but in my case it doesn't work because all the properties related to width and height (`Width`, `Height`, `ActualWidth`, `ActualHeight`, `ActualSize`, `RenderSize`, etc.) are equal to `0` or `NaN` at runtime. Maybe because it's a Polygon...?